# generate template from database

Tags: laravel, phpword

I'm trying to work with the PhpWord library for generating a Word file using Laravel.

I search for the documentation of this library and how it worked, I found that I should have already a template to work with.

But In my case, I should create this template from the database and then generate this file in word format.

I'm trying the following code :

```
$preambule = DB::table('modele_contrat')->select('preambule')->where('id_modele_contrat', $value['id_modele_contrat'])->value('preambule');                         
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$text = $section->addText($preambule);
 $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
 $objWriter->save('testt.docx');
 return response()->download(public_path('testt.docx'));
```

But in this case the file does not open with the error, problems are detected in the content of the file.

But when I change the code of this line :
`$text = $section->addText($preambule);`

to :

```
 $text = $section->addText("hello");
```

The file opens normally.

When I did dd($preambule) to see the value of this variable, I get the value stored in database column, a varchar elements.

Comment: I think the problem is with your query use this: `$preambule = DB::table('modele_contrat')->where('id_modele_contrat', $value['id_modele_contrat'])->get();` and `$preambule->preambule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$preambule = DB::table('modele_contrat')->where('id_modele_contrat', $value['id_modele_contrat'])->value('preambule');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$sectionStyle = array(
    //'orientation'       =>      'landscape',
    'marginTop'         =>      600,
    'marginRight'       =>      600,
    'marginBottom'      =>      600,
    'marginLeft'        =>      600,
    //'text-align'        =>      'right',
    'footerHeight'      =>      100
);

$section = $phpWord->addSection($sectionStyle);

$section->addText($preambule);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
try {
    $objWriter->save(storage_path('preambule.docx'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
return response()->download(storage_path('preambule.docx'));
```